# Connecting a data set to a visual studio form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to connect a data set to a visual studio form. I'm basically using a pattern matching algorithm to scan through a network data set and cant figure out how to connect the data set to the form? the data set is a .txt file by the way. Can anyone help please?

Comment: This is your first post so help us help you... post some code that isn't working, describe the problem more fully - what UI technology - Winforms or WPF?  How are you reading in your txt file - Into an object?  Show your object model if so.

Comment: I'm using winforms Kevin. I'm using the Aho-Corasick pattern matching algorithm to scan through a KDDCup data set to identify pre-determined patterns . I suppose my question is what options are available to me? Do I use a stream reader? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: If you're reading the data from a text file then you probably would use a StreamReader.  What you do with the data then depends on what you want to do with the data.  There is no "connection" with the form.  You put the data into an appropriate data structure and then you display in an appropriate way.  You need to make some decisions about how you WANT it to work before you then decide how to implement that.